# Remote Administration of Windows XP through the Command Line

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, ssh, administration

Does anyone know of a good way to do remote administration of a Windows XP machine using just the command line?

At the moment the only things it needs to do is to be able to install applications/patches, and transfer files to and from the machine, and installing registry patches would be nice as well.

Currently we use a horrible hacked together solution that uses NetMeeting, in the past I've thrown together a proof of concept using SSH for windows (at the time windows 2000) but it didn't work to my satisfaction and was pretty buggy. Which was probably the result of the SSH Daemon I was running more then anything.

I'm pretty much open to anything, however a solution using SSH would be ideal since it's already approved for installation in my organization, and it's free. I work in the Canadian Government so anything free is best, and anything that we've already got approved for installation is even better.

Answer (score 7):

[psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) will allow you to run commands remotely. Some of the other PsTools can help you kill applications, get a list of processes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me, I'm familiar with PsTools and have used them in the past. Although I've never worked with PSEXec before, hopefully they've got these tools approved in my department so I can actually use them.

Comment: Great alternative to SSH for Windows ! I use that to connect remotely: `psexec \\remote_ip -u Administrator "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` It seems slower than SSH. Any idea of the port used ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Software Testing Automation Framework (STAF)](http://staf.sourceforge.net/) is designed for remote access, installing software, transferring files. etc. It's open source and you can write your own service if there isn't one that does what you need. It also has a GUI component for writing, scheduling, queueing and monitoring jobs across a pool of machines.

Answer (score 1):

Why must it be

> remote administration of a Windows XP machine using just the command line?

I think your very limiting yourself to what is possible by sticking to the command line.  In windows environments you can easily use Group Policy to distribute most software and/or patches, and for the ones that you can't you can usually script these changes through any of the popular scripting languages such as JScript, VBScript, Kixtart, AutoIt, Powershell, etc.  With these scripting languages you can easily leverage WMI to exceute and mointor processes on remotes systems, copy files, updates registry...basically everything that you're trying to accomplish....and it won't cost you anything but the cost of learning these technologies, and there many online resources and which document how to do them.  Here is a link to the Microsoft Script Center, its a great start: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/default.mspx

Comment: We are using Group Policy and WMI to manage our network and I'm very familiar with these technologies. Unfortunately for myself the network I am administering is hampered by design decisions made in the past, and we still require remote administration of the machines using other technologies.

Comment: I simply don't have a choice in this matter, it must be because it is. If you were to work in a place as mired in bureaucracy as mine is then you'd understand. Right now as I've said we used a hacked together NetMeeting to do this job. I'm looking for something a little better.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this a while back, and used it to maintain my home windows XP desktop for a while:
[ssh and telnet on windows](http://roqet.org/ssh_and_telnet_on_windows.html)

I used the SSH option (not telnet). It worked for my purposes (killing remote tasks, copying files etc.) It uses Cygwin, but you're able to run regular windows commands as well as the bash commands that come with cygwin.

Comment: Unfortunately for reasons beyond my control I'm unable to use Cygwin, as much as I would love to be able to. This combined with SSH would be my ideal solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> At the moment the only things it needs to do is to be able to install
>   applications/patches, and transfer files to and from the machine, and
>   installing registry patches would be nice as well.

try to download and install eurysco to use in order:

1. transfer file, applications and patches with multiple-upload feature from eurysco file browser
2. install applications and patches in silent mode from eurysco command line feature
3. edit registry from eurysco system-registry feature

http://www.eurysco.com/features