# Windows: running a process on a remote machine

Tags: windows

How can I launch a program on a remote windows machine, so that it uses the remote's machine processor and ram.

details:
i have mapped another computers folder to a local drive. in this folder i want to launch an exe via a windows batch file so that it uses the remote computers ressources and not the local ones.

Comment: Do you want a local UI for the process?  Ie: do you want to be able to control the program as though it was a local application?  Is this a windows application or a console application?  Do you need to pass it information?  Do you need it to pass information back?  Is remote desktop a solution?  Why or why not?

Comment: no UI needed, it's an exe that does some stuff in the background. no information to pass either way necessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666611/remote-administration-of-windows-xp-through-the-command-line

Answer (score 4):

Use sysinternals (now on microsoft) PsExec.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, You can't launch an exe on a remote machine unless you are logged into that remote machine in some way. Either by Remote Desktop Connection or through some shell.

Comment: thanks, does connecting to a shared drive count as being logged in?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't let you run processes on the remote machine. it only gives you access to files.

Comment: @minaz actually you can start processes on a remote machine using regular Windows networking (under the hood, this uses the IPC share).  One way is to copy an executable over and then install it as a system service, this is what PsExec does.  The OpenSCManager function allows you to specify a remote machine.  There may well be other methods.